# Doing something with the ID of each checked box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've just learned that we can iterate through all checkboxes in a document, but I'm unclear on how to do anything with the values or properties of the checkboxes found.

Here's my code:

```
    function buildrow(){
    $("input[type=checkbox][checked]").each( 
        function() { 
            alert($this.attr('id');//This doesn't work
        } 
    );
}
```

How do we do pull a value out and do something with it? Such as pull the value for the ID and set it as a variable?

Thanks

Comment: You have not defined `$this` and you are a missing a `)`. You should probably have a look at the [documentation for `.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/). Reading some tutorial might help as well to get a better understanding of jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function buildrow(){    
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function()
    {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        // do something with the id..
        alert(id);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use standard DOM property access, rather than wrapping each checkbox with jQuery again:

```
alert(this.id)
```

should work.  You might also want to use `input[type="checkbox"]:checked` as your selector, taking care to include the quotation marks.  As a general rule, I shy away from invented selectors like `:checkbox`, as other developers could be misled into thinking this is a genuine CSS selector.

Comment: I'm interested in this but am too new to know how to take that line and incorporate it into my code while ensuring that I only get those items that are :checked.

Comment: @ChadM: more or less the same as the accepted answer, but `var id = $(this).attr('id')` would be replaced with `var id = this.id`.  Note that `attr` is a particularly evil function for several reasons, but mostly because it's used by people in the most redundant way.  I have [a blog post](http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/10/utilizing-the-awesome-power-of-jquery-to-access-properties-of-an-element) outlining some of the issues, though they apply more to older versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

`alert( $(this).attr('id') ); //This does work`

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are missing a closing bracket and also to access an id you can get it from DOM element itself. Try this

```
function buildrow(){
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each( 
        function() { 
            alert(this.id);//This doesn't work
        } 
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$this should be $(this) or if you are going to use $this because it looks neat or convenient or whatever, you have to assign $(this) to $this like

```
function buildrow(){
    $("input:checkbox").each(function(index,element) {
            $this = $(element);
            alert($this.attr('id'));//This doesn't work
        } 
    );
}
```

Also your alert function is not correct, you are missing a ) at the end, I've made other corrections to your main function body as well. I hope that helps.